# Rails 4, Argument Error Unknown Key, Update Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I receive an error when trying to edit a post:

**posts#edit controller:**

```
def edit
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
end
```

posts#update controller:

```
def update
 @post = Post.find params[:post]

 if @post.update_attributes params[:post]
  redirect_to posts_path
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end
```

**edit view:**

```
h1 Edit Post
= form_for @post do |f|
 p
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
 p
  br
 p
  = f.label :content
  = f.text_area :content
 p
  br
 p
  = f.submit 'Update Post'
 p
  br
```

This is when I get the *ArgumentError in PostsController#update, Unknown Key: title* error.  I am still wrapping my head around the strong parameter concept in Rails 4 so it might have something to do with this...any ideas?

Comment: have you tested the controller actions in the rails console?  Does `Post.find(id: <id-number>)` return what you expect?

Comment: what is the browser url when you get this error?

Comment: Yes Nikola, Post.find(13) inside of the console returns what is expected...

Comment: the browser reads "http://localhost:3000/posts/13/edit"

Comment: replace 'update_attributes' to 'update'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following i hope it will help you.

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the posts#update controller to

```
params[:id]
```

rather than

```
params[:post]
```

this fix brought me the *ForbiddenAttributesError* caused by

```
if @post.update_attributes params[:post]
```

this is due to the strong parameters concept introduced with Rails 4...I fixed this by substituting the

```
params[:post]
```

with a strong parameter

```
post_params
```

from the private method post_params

```
 private
  def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
 end
```

eventually solving the unknown key error of :title